# Session login not logging out on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I currently have a site which stores variables on a user login, from a DB. One such variable (on a successful login) is `SiteSession.Current.IsLoggedIn = true`.

When I click the logout button, my method tells it to set that to `false`, then proceed to `Session.Clear()` and `Session.Abandon()`.

Up to now, I have to click the logout button twice before any changes are made.
I tested with `Response.Write(SiteSession.Current.IsLoggedIn);` in my `Logout()` method.

The first click doesnt show anything, then the second click shows `false`.

Could anyone tell me where I;m going wrong?

```
/// <summary>
/// Logs the user out, and destroys the session
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void lnkAccountLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SiteSession.Current.IsLoggedIn = false;
    SiteSession.Current.RollId = "-1";

    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Write(SiteSession.Current.IsLoggedIn);
}
```

~ The login is basically the opposite to that, whilest storing a few more variables.

**Edit:** If I reload the page after I click the first time, nothing happens.

Comment: It might be related to the viewstate/postback. I haven't worked in ASP.Net in a while but I think if(!IsPostBack){code} would work

Comment: Hey.. That /works/ per say.. Unfortunatly, it completley messes up my login :/ With that, it doesnt store anything..

Comment: You gotta do the same in the login method. You should read about the viewstate, it can be quite confusing

Comment: you can try to add it in your function 'disconnect' -> Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest (); ?

Comment: @fhlamarche looks like i need to do that :D

Answer (score 0):

It may cost some time to store the changes in the db. Try to let it run in another thread and let the thread wait till IsLoggedIn is true.

I hope that helps =)

Comment: By other, non related research, I learnt that running threads in a development Webserver isnt the best thing :) Also, the db is local to the server - changes are made instantly... I doubt this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The way I got round clearing `session` was to make a class of my `Session`

```
 private Boolean _isNew = true;
 public Boolean isNew
    {
        get { return _isNew; }
        set { _isNew = value; }

    }
```

on page load check if it `isNew` if it was I

Session.Clear();

Session.Abandon();

When I had finished with `Session` I just made a new instance of that `Session`

//clear session

SessionVars.Current.Incident = new Incident();